# how to consume kafka topics in sequence in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

i have a problem i made an apache kafka consumer in spring boot to consume 3 different topics. but I need to consume all the data from the first topic first and then consume the data from the following topics, is there any way to do that? or will you always read them the same way?

```
@Component
public class KafkaTestListener {

@KafkaListener(topics = "${message.topic.name}", groupId = "${message.group.name}")
    public void listenTopic1(String message) {....}

@KafkaListener(topics = "${message.topic.name2}", groupId = "${message.group.name}")
    public void listenTopic3(String message) {....}

@KafkaListener(topics = "${message.topic.name3}", groupId = "${message.group.name}")
    public void listenTopic3(String message) {.....}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Give each listener an `id`; set `autoStartup` to `false`.
- Set the container property `idleEventInterval` to some value.
- Add an `@EventListener` method to receive `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`s - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#events and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#event-consumption
- Use the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` to start and stop the containers (via `id`) as needed.